# Can someone please explain what this command does?

Tags: kali-linux

I understand the first part of the command `sudo apt-get install -y`, but do not understand the rest.

```
sudo apt-get install -y dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The remainder of your `apt-get` command is specifying the packages you want to install.  In this case, you have chosen two packages: `dkms` (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) and the linux header files for your currently running version of the linux kernel.

[`uname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uname) returns some basic information about your system; the `-r` option specifies the running kernel version.  The `$()` shell construct in the command gets replaced by the output of the command contained within parentheses.  `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` is a generic copy-pastable way to specify headers needed for the current kernel, as opposed to explicitly typing a version as `linux-headers-4.4.0.101-generic`.

[This general question on Kali](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) may also be relevant.

Comment: Why am I being ban for asking general questions ? Is this site not for learning because all my posts keep getting flagged, I'm so confused, maybe I got the wrong site to be asking questions on. Can a mod or someone please tell me how I contact someone from the site?

Comment: @HardRebootHackerHD, check the [help page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for this stack to see what are appropriate questions.  Given the questions you've asked recently, I'd also strongly recommend the general Kali question already linked in my answer.

Comment: Read the question guidelines of the Unix and linux site. If you get more reputation you'll be able to ask about the site on the meta, which is the correct place for this question, not this comment. Also try the chat if you can.